# /usr/local/include/string.h:25:10: fatal error: 'plist/Node.h' file not found

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, clang, clang++

Im trying to run a hello world program in C++ in MacOS. Trying to run it using the terminal using command `g++ -o test.cpp test`

Its giving me the above error. Do i need to reinstall my compiler somehow and if yes then how do i do that?

clang++ and g++ and gcc.
I have xcode already setup.

I've also installed `xcode-select --install` as i read somewhere.

I've tried all of these to run the program. They have their versions like this

`clang++ -v`

```
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

`g++ -v`

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Please read [ask] with a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Is that g++ command a typo or did you try to set the output file as test.cpp?
How did you install g++?

is this the only error you get?

```sh
/usr/local/include/string.h:25:10: fatal error: 'plist/Node.h' file not found
```

What happens if you run

```sh
g++ -o test -Wall test.cpp
```

Comment: It still gives the same error. Installed g++ like this http://www.edparrish.net/common/macgpp.php

Comment: Your code is just a simple hello world? you're only including iostream? It's kinda hard to help when you don't supply your code

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "positive";
    return 0;
}
Thats the code.

Comment: Include the << endl; after your cout. Not that it matters, your code runs fine eitherway. Did you try rebooting after installing?